# Twitter Search Query API V1.1 ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, twitter

I have recently found that the Twitter API V1 is no longer working and I need to migrate to V1.1. I am getting the following message:
"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview."

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=Twitter&rpp=30

However, after reading all the documentation and realising that I need to use OAuth with this new version I cannot find any C# code to use in ASP.net as a starting point. What I am looking to do is search for a list of keywords and download all tweets for this keyword. It was working up until last month using API v1. Does anyone have any support material that shows this type of solution? The only ones I can see are downloading and displaying a user's timeline.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several open-source .NET libraries that would be great places to check out.

TweetSharp - [GitHub repository](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp)

Twitterizer (no longer updated, but code is still valid) - [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer)

TwitterVB (no longer updated, but code is still valid) - [GitHub repository](https://github.com/DWRoelands/TwitterVB)

(Full disclosure: TwitterVB is the library that I wrote.  I recommend you start with TweetSharp).

Comment: I'm having issues with TweetSharp. It too is discontinued. Do you recommend any tutorials or should I just dive into Twitterizer or VB?

Comment: Right now, I'm not aware of any .NET libraries for Twitter that are currently being actively maintained.  Twitterizer and Tweetsharp were both better than my library and I believe they both work with Twitter API 1.1.  Twitterizer's a solid library, even though it's not in active development.